# Android predefined input

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-input-method

How can I create an input in my xml for predefined inputs for specific values? For example, I want a user to input blood pressure which can be 120/80, so in my input I would like the user to type in an input field that has a forward slash already placed. Please advise.
This is what I have

[image]

The closest I have to that is this

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/patientBloodPressure1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.45"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="@string/slash"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_weight="0.75"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/patientBloodPressure2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Let me get it right: you want two separate fields divided by slash filled with default values and not a hint. Right?

Comment: Not exactly, a hint can work too. I just want the above, wondering whether there is any easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few options.
First you could try combining 2 edittext, one for before the slash and one for after (and make sure they look like a single one)

Second option is to use a TextWatcher, pretty much like they do in credit card expiry date

```
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if (before == 1 && count == 2 && s.charAt(s.length()-1) != '/') {
         editText.setText(editText.getText() += "/";
    }
    if (editText.getText().toString().toCharArray().length < 3) {
         editText.setText(editText.getText().toString().replace("/", ""));
    } 
} 
});
```

And last, creating a customized edittext like this one:
https://github.com/woxingxiao/XEditText

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it as simple,

you should use text watcher which also helps you to validate values at runtime.

you can add your validation in textwatcher eg:

divided string into two parts and check for the int values that these belongs to your respective values or not.

also add a separator(-) when string will cross its length above 3

Answer (score 0):

Using a `TextWatcher` will be really difficult. You could fall in some edge cases where people with a low blood pressure should be able to type 80/50, and in this cases you cant use the 3 digits splits to add automatically add a `/` between the values.

I would suggest you to use 2 separate fields as you did, using the `android:hint` to provide a better description. Like

```
Blood Pressure (TextView Label)
_____MAX_____ / ______MIN______
```